# Maximum attribute size limit (65536) exceeds. Mulesoft

Tags: mule, dataweave, xml-attribute

I am sending an XML payload to a webservice and capturing the response payload in dataweave transformer. For some payload data, I am getting the expected response, but for some of them, I am getting this below error. Can anyone know, how to resolve this error in Mule 3 dataweave 1.0 ? I am using below dataweave transformation.

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" >
                <dw:input-payload  mimeType="application/xml">
        <dw:reader-property name="maxAttributeSize" value="1000000"/>
    </dw:input-payload>
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
                </dw:transform-message>
```

> "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum attribute size limit (65536) exceeded (java.io.IOException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException).",

Comment: Which is the exact Mule version?

Comment: I am using 3.9.4 runtime version.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you reached the limit of the size of the attribute. There is a `maxAttributeSize` reader property that you can configure to increase the size. The size is the amount of characters an attribute can have.

Comment: I am using that reader property <dw:reader-property name="maxAttributeSize" value="1000000"/> I increased the value, but it is still giving me that error.

Comment: how big is the biggest attribute in the XML input?

Comment: its an base64 string which is around 87kb

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is the one suggested by @machaval, however there are some known issues that prevent it to work in some versions of Mule. It should work correctly in Mule 3.9.4.

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-parse-XML-attributes-larger-than-524288

Comment: I followed that exact link and set the reader property. I am working on Mule 3.9.4